# How can I keep a fixed size for one row in a bootstrap responsive table?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, responsive

I use the responsive table from bootstrap. I want to keep the first row always be 500px. But when I change the window size, it doesn't stay 500px:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:500px">#</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: try using `min-width:500px;` instead.

Comment: @Option Great! Didn't think of that! Working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `width:500px` to `min-width:500px;` and job done :-)

Answer (score 2):

This should probably fix it. However you will have problems with the responsive nature.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="min-width:500px">#</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```